# Android: Add both search recent suggests and custom suggests

Tags: android, android-search

I want to add some suggestions for a search widget and I don't know how to show both recent and custom suggestions. The snippet below gives me an

CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Requested column: 4, # of columns: 4

Any ideas?

**My code for the custom suggestions**

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
    suggestions.add("iphone");
    Cursor recentCursor = super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY } );
    for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.size(); ++i) {
        String suggestion = suggestions.get(i);
        Object[] row = { Integer.toString(i),
                suggestion,
                suggestion, suggestion };
        cursor.addRow(row);
    }

    Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[] { recentCursor, cursor};
    return new MergeCursor(cursors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

recentCursor has 5th column which is SUGGEST_COLUMN_FORMAT, so you can not merge 5 columns to 4

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've forgotten to add `SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1` column to the cursor.